# How to add checkbox option for series string inputs in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I want to figure out how to allow a series string to be plotted in cross style format but as a checkbox function. Unfortunaly, I couldn't find any resources that gave an example of this type of use case, so let's create one.

First, Here's an example of a working standard input string works when plotted such that it can be enabled as an option.

```
testfunction = sma(rsi, 7)
show_testfunction = input(false, "Show testfunction", type=input.bool)

plot(show_testfunction ? testfunction : na, "Test Function", color.white, transp=30, linewidth=2)
```

However when wanting to have the same type of checkbox option for a series string, given it allows for `style=plot.cross_style`, I experience the following error:

```
Syntax error at input 'series'.
```

I write the following code to get the issue:

Testfunctionseries = sma (rsi, 3)

```
show_testfunctionseries = input(false, "Show series testfunction", type=input.bool)

plot(show_testfunctionseries ? series=testfunctionseries : na, "Test Function Series With Cross Style",  style=plot.style_cross, color.white, transp=30, linewidth=2)
```

Here's how the same line of code works when plotted without a checkbox option:

```
plot(series=testfunctionseries, style=plot.style_cross, color=color.purple, title="Testfunction Series Cross", transp=70, linewidth=2)
```

Also, I hope this thread was helpful for pine devs who didn't know these types of functions.

Answer (score 0):

You use the argument name `series=` incorrectly. The whole expression `show_testfunctionseries ? testfunctionseries : na` should be passed to `series=` for your code to work. Here is how the code should look for it to compile properly:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
testfunctionseries = sma(rsi, 3)
show_testfunctionseries = input(false, "Show series testfunction", type=input.bool)
plot(series = show_testfunctionseries ? testfunctionseries : na, title = "Test Function Series With Cross Style",  style=plot.style_cross, color=color.white, transp=30, linewidth=2)
```

Note that I also added `title=` and `color=` there. Once you use a keyword to refer to an argument (in your case, `series=`), you can no longer use positional arguments in the same function call, you must use keywords for the code to compile. You can use both positional and keyword arguments only when all of the positional ones are before the first keyword argument:

```
plot(show_testfunctionseries ? testfunctionseries : na, "Test Function Series With Cross Style",  style=plot.style_cross, color=color.white, transp=30, linewidth=2)
```